# How to show two dashboard snapshots on home page layout in Salesforce?

Tags: dashboard, home-page-component, report-chart, home-page-layout

There is only one dashboard snapshot available for home page in salesforce, is there any way to show two different dashboard snapshots. As in standard functionality only one row of dashboard is displayed not the complete dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help you
Check This Link
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2riAAA,
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goerAAA